# TemplateNotFound(template) with Google App Engine & Jinja2

Tags: google-app-engine, jinja2

I'm getting a TemplateNotFound error on Google App Engine with Jinja2 (complete stack trace below.)

What I expect to see is the index.html with the "greet" variable passed to the index.html template file.  What I don't understand is why I get the template not found error when the path to index.html in the TraceBack is correct.

What I've tried...

- tried a relative path by taking out "os.path.dirname(**file**)" in template path.
- using "template" instead of themes as a directory name.

Here is my code.

**app.yaml**

```
application: codemywayout
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:

- url: /admin/.*
  script: admin.app
  login: admin

- url: /static/([^/]+)/(.*)
  static_files: template/\1/static/\2
  upload: static/.*

- url: /favicon\.ico
  static_files: favicon.ico
  upload: favicon\.ico

- url: .*
  script: static.app

builtins:
- remote_api: on

libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: "2.5.1"
- name: jinja2
  version: latest
```

**admin.py**

```
from google.appengine.ext import db
import webapp2
import jinja2
import os
import fix_path
import config


def render_template(template_name, template_vals=None, theme=None):
    template_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__) , \
            "themes", theme or config.theme, template_name)
    env = jinja2.Environment(
        loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader(template_path))
    return env.get_template(template_path, template_vals or {})

class BlogPost(db.Model):
    title = db.StringProperty()
    body = db.StringProperty()

def render(self):
    template_vals = {
        'config': config,
        'post': self,
    }
    return render_template("post.html", template_vals)

class BaseHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def render_to_response(self, template_name, \
            template_vals=None, theme=None):
        template_name = os.path.join("admin", template_name)
        self.response.out.write(render_template(template_name,\
            template_vals, theme))

class AdminHandler(BaseHandler):
    def get(self):
        greet = "hello"
        template_vals = {
            'greet': greet
        }
        self.render_to_response("index.html", template_vals)
```

**config.py**

```
# Name of the blog
blog_name = 'My Blog'

# Selects the theme to use. Theme names correspond to directories under
# the 'themes' directory, containing templates and static content.
theme = 'default'

# Defines the URL organization to use for blog postings. Valid substitutions:
#   slug - the identifier for the post, derived from the title
#   year - the year the post was published in
#   month - the month the post was published in
#   day - the day the post was published in

# URL Options
#   post_path_format = '/%(year)d/%(month)02d/%(slug)s'
post_path_format = '/%(slug)s'
```

**TraceBack**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\john\webdev\google\lib\webapp2\webapp2.py", line 1536, in __call__
    rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)
  File "C:\Users\john\webdev\google\lib\webapp2\webapp2.py", line 1530, in __call__
    rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)
  File "C:\Users\john\webdev\google\lib\webapp2\webapp2.py", line 1278, in default_dispatcher
    return route.handler_adapter(request, response)
  File "C:\Users\john\webdev\google\lib\webapp2\webapp2.py", line 1102, in __call__
    return handler.dispatch()
  File "C:\Users\john\webdev\google\lib\webapp2\webapp2.py", line 572, in dispatch
    return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)
  File "C:\Users\john\webdev\google\lib\webapp2\webapp2.py", line 570, in dispatch
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\john\webdev\workspace\codemywayout\admin.py", line 49, in get
    self.render_to_response("index.html", template_vals)
  File "C:\Users\john\webdev\workspace\codemywayout\admin.py", line 34, in render_to_response
    template_vals, theme))
  File "C:\Users\john\webdev\workspace\codemywayout\admin.py", line 14, in render_template
    return env.get_template(template_path, template_vals or {})
  File "C:\Users\john\webdev\google\lib\jinja2\jinja2\environment.py", line 719, in get_template
    return self._load_template(name, self.make_globals(globals))
  File "C:\Users\john\webdev\google\lib\jinja2\jinja2\environment.py", line 693, in _load_template
    template = self.loader.load(self, name, globals)
  File "C:\Users\john\webdev\google\lib\jinja2\jinja2\loaders.py", line 115, in load
    source, filename, uptodate = self.get_source(environment, name)
  File "C:\Users\john\webdev\google\lib\jinja2\jinja2\loaders.py", line 162, in get_source
    pieces = split_template_path(template)
  File "C:\Users\john\webdev\google\lib\jinja2\jinja2\loaders.py", line 33, in split_template_path
    raise TemplateNotFound(template)
TemplateNotFound: C:\Users\john\webdev\workspace\codemywayout\themes\default\admin\index.html
```

Comment: what is the absolute path of your index.html template file?

Answer (score 1):

I hope your not trying to load the Jinja template from the same path as your static files

static_files: template/\1/static/\2

As that path is not accessible to your application.

I would try and log the path that Jinja is trying to load the template from to help you understand where it is trying to load the template.

Comment: please help with this for me if you can https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67661017/jinja2-template-not-found-unsolved

Answer (score 0):

If you look at C:\Users\john\webdev\google\lib\jinja2\jinja2\loaders.py line 33 you can probably set a pdb breakpoint `import pdb; pdb.set_trace( )` and see what's going on.

I'm using the SDK source distribution on a Mac, but if your code is the same as what I see, it's:

```
def split_template_path(template):
    """Split a path into segments and perform a sanity check.  If it detects
    '..' in the path it will raise a `TemplateNotFound` error.
    """
    pieces = []
    for piece in template.split('/'):
        if path.sep in piece \
           or (path.altsep and path.altsep in piece) or \
           piece == path.pardir:
            raise TemplateNotFound(template)
        elif piece and piece != '.':
            pieces.append(piece)
    return pieces
```

Note the `for piece in template.split('/')` where it splits on '/' instead of `path.sep`. I suspect that your input is a C:\Path\to\file.html in which case piece is the entire path, adn path.sep (\ on windows) is indeed in piece, which gives a TemplateNotFound error.

Instead of `template_name = os.path.join("admin", template_name)` you could try `template_name = 'admin/%s' % template_name`, don't include template_name in the template_path and pass template_name instead of template_path into `env.get_template(template_name, template_vals or {})` as loaders.py line 162 indicates that it looks for template_name in template_path

Your code, modified but untested would look something like

```
from google.appengine.ext import db
import webapp2
import jinja2
import os
import fix_path
import config


def render_template(template_name, template_vals=None, theme=None):
    template_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__) , \
            "themes", theme or config.theme)
    env = jinja2.Environment(
        loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader(template_path))
    return env.get_template(template_name, template_vals or {})

class BlogPost(db.Model):
    title = db.StringProperty()
    body = db.StringProperty()

def render(self):
    template_vals = {
        'config': config,
        'post': self,
    }
    return render_template("post.html", template_vals)

class BaseHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def render_to_response(self, template_name, \
            template_vals=None, theme=None):
        template_name = "admin/%s" % template_name
        self.response.out.write(render_template(template_name,\
            template_vals, theme))

class AdminHandler(BaseHandler):
    def get(self):
        greet = "hello"
        template_vals = {
            'greet': greet
        }
        self.render_to_response("index.html", template_vals)
```

Comment: please help with this for me if you can https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67661017/jinja2-template-not-found-unsolved