# jinja2 template not found - unsolved

Tags: html, templates, jinja2

I receive this error:

```
Exception has occurred: TemplateNotFound
```

I have read dozens of answers to questions whose symptoms appear to match mine, but none of them worked for me. For example, I already have the html files placed into a templates folder.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Must change the path to templates folder to include the folders that contain it.

```
file_loader = FileSystemLoader('Tools\\CustomMikraotGedolot\\templates',
```

instead of

```
file_loader = FileSystemLoader('templates',
```